# How to retrieve all tweets from user twitter api + javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am trying to store every tweet from a user in an array. Firstly, I'm trying to get the first 3200 tweets from a user.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
require('dotenv/config');

const apikey = process.env.apikey
const apiSecretKey = process.env.apikeysecret
const accessToken = process.env.accesstoken
const accessTokenSecret = process.env.accesstokensecret

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: apikey,
    consumer_secret: apiSecretKey,
    access_token_key: accessToken,
    access_token_secret: accessTokenSecret
});

var mastertweetsarray = [];


var the_latest_id = null

function getlastid (){
  var params = {screen_name: 'example', count: 200};
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
      the_latest_id = tweets[tweets.length - 1].id
      for (i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        mastertweetsarray.push(tweets[i].text)
      }
    }
  });
}

function getothertweets() {
  var paramssecond = {screen_name: 'example', count: 200, max_id: the_latest_id};
  for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    console.log("this is trial" + j)
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', paramssecond, function(error, tweets, response) {
      if (!error) {
        for (i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
          mastertweetsarray.push(tweets[i].text)
        }
        if (tweets.length - 1 == -1) {
          return;
        } else {
          the_latest_id = tweets[tweets.length - 1].id
        }
        //use for loop to go through every tweet and and use includes() to get specific keywords
      }
    });
  }
}

async function runeverything() {
  await getlastid();
  await getothertweets();
  return mastertweetsarray;
}

console.log(runeverything())
```

This is what I have so far just getting the user timeline and repeating the storing part 15 times after I get the last id from the first 200. Then, saving the last id as the max_id for the other 15 times. What are some ways to make this work and improve it? Also, is there a way to get all tweets from a user?

Comment: As per development doc, there's no way to retrieve all tweets of a user. You can maximum fetch 200 tweets at once from API.

Comment: So there is no way to get more than 200?

Comment: Nope! There's no other way to do it.